# Set the current user to the model when posting a form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to add the request user to a model.

```
def fileupload(request):
files = Download.objects
if request.method == "POST" :
    form = DownloadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        author = request.user
        savefile = form.save()
        savefile.save()
```

My models is :

```
class Download(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="filedownload")
upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

But the author is not updating, any clue ?

Comment: `author = request.user` and where do you assign the author to the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `author` to your form object. The exact way to do that depends on your form class -- so maybe include that in your post.

Try something like this:

```
def fileupload(request):
    files = Download.objects
    if request.method == "POST" :
        form = DownloadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.author = request.user  # <--- changed to `form.author`
            savefile = form.save()
            savefile.save()
```

Comment: I tried your code it does not work, i don't understand

Comment: It works I just had to changed form.author to  savefile.author = request.user